How to create virtual audio devices in linux
How do I setup virtual audio devices in Nobara linux. I am new to linux and want to switch over from windows but I need this solved first.
In windows I use the program vb-audio.com/Cable/ to have my apps send the audio output to virtual outputs and then I have those virtual outputs send the feed to my headset. It helps when I am recording in OBS and want to select certain audio feeds only to be recorded.
I need two virtual Devices
one that intakes my discord sound
one that intakes the current game I am playing sound

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
